# How can I load a script only if no internet connection is detected?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have some jquery plugins in my web pages as well Google Analytics script . A photo slider is one of my those jquery plugins. I have put google analytics at the bottom of page after all other js files calling. But Users in the our internal network without an internet connection can not see photos of the photo slider because all the jquery codes run after the page is loaded completely. and the page isn't completely loaded because of google analytics can't connect to internet.

Is there any way that I can load Google Analytics script only if the user has access to the internet?

Comment: GA snippet is asynchronous and non-blocking (and should be place at top, not bottom). So there is a problem with your plugin : you should better debug it instead of remove GA code...

Comment: I altered your question. The correct question should be how to load a script only if internet connection is available.

Comment: You can try making an ajax request for a small file (what you make the request for isn't actually important, your basically just *pinging*) and in the success callback load the Google Analytics script, but for the same price you can just try loading the Google Analytics script since as @greg mentioned it is asynchronous